# Can randoop generate test making use of user-made JUnit test?

Tags: java, testing, randoop

I want to know whether Randoop can make use of already existing (user-made) test cases.

I read through [user's manual](https://randoop.github.io/randoop/manual/), but I don't think there's any part related to this.

I just would like to know whether this is possible or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share your personal effort to find an answer

Comment: Can you clarify what you want Randoop to do with the existing test cases?